Optimizing High-Throughput WebSocket Server in Node.js for Low Latency
I’m developing a high-throughput WebSocket server in Node.js that needs to handle thousands of connections with low latency. The server uses the ws library for WebSocket communication, but I’m encountering performance issues as the number of connections scales.
Here are some issues that I'm facing:

Latency: The latency increases significantly under heavy load. I need to understand how to optimize the WebSocket server to minimize latency.
Resource Management: Managing CPU and memory usage effectively as the number of connections grows. How can I optimize resource usage?

Any recommendations or examples of handling such issues ?
I tried to use multiple instances of the WebSocket server behind a load balancer to distribute connections.
But still it doesn't reduce the high latency
